# Custom throttling problems

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, throttling

i have:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    verification = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
```

In my viewset I must limit the number of requests to my endpoint from device by his verification.

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
      permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
      throttle_classes = (UserPhoneThrottle,)

      serializer_class_map = {
          ...,
          'verify': serializers.VerifyCodeSerializer,
      }
```

I try to write my custom throttle:

```
class UserPhoneThrottle(throttling.SimpleRateThrottle):

    def get_cache_key(self, request, view):
        verification_id = request.data.get('verification_id')

        if not verification_id:
             return None
        else:
             return self.cache_format % {
                 'scope': self.scope,
                 'ident': verification_id
             }
```

In my settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
         'app.throttling.UserPhoneThrottle',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        ...?
     }
}
```

I ask to help or assist correctly to finish the given logic and to prompt what is this an error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You must set either `.scope` or `.rate` for 'UserPhoneThrottle' throttle

**I will be very grateful for the help. Thank you!)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty ***straightforward***, 
You should **either** set something like this in **`settings.py`** as,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'app.throttling.UserPhoneThrottle',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'user': '1000/day'
    }
}
```

**OR**
set **`.scope`** in **`UserPhoneThrottle`** in as,

```
class UserPhoneThrottle(throttling.SimpleRateThrottle):
    scope = 'user'
    # your code
```